# Output argument "val" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to

Tags: matlab, colors, runtime-error, pixel

I have the following function that aims to set a colour to a specific pixel.

```
function val = xyz(p)
if (p(2,2)) == 40
val=[255,0,0];
end
end
```

I'm not sure if the function works correct in assigning the colour since I get the following error when I call the function:

```
Output argument "val" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to.....
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: If val is not assigned, then `p(2,2)` obviously does not equal `40`... you should probably add an `else` version here.

Answer (score 0):

Sebastian said right, you need to add an else to be sure your output is fill.

```
function val = xyz(p)
  if (p(2,2)) == 40
    val=[255,0,0];
  else 
    val = [];
  end
end
```